# Merge two git repositories into one, keeping (renamed) master branches

Tags: git, version-control, merge, branch

### Preamble

I have two separate projects that grew into one. They both have their own `git` repository.

```
/project/
/project/app/
/project/app/.git/
/project/helper/
/project/helper/.git/
```

Both `git` repositories have some unique branches, and both have of course their own `master` branch.

### Question

I would like to merge both projects into one like so:

```
/project/.git/
```

The unique branches aren't relevant and they can be removed. But I would like the master branches to be renamed and kept, e.g. `masterApp` and `masterHelper`, so that I have a new single repository for the whole project with both branches and a new `master` branch.

Is this possible?
If so, it would involve some renaming trickery because each repository suddenly includes their own parent directory.

### Details

These repositories are local for now, so we don't have to worry about remote origins or breaking the commit history for other users. I do want to keep the commit history for the individual (renamed) `master` branches though, and (if possible) the files that are staged/tracked in those branches.

---

I have found the following similar question: [How do you merge two git repositories?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1425892/how-do-you-merge-two-git-repositories)

That question is about merging one repository *into* the other repository. That makes this question slightly different, but I think the solution might be close. However, I am not experienced enough with `git` to figure out how that solution would apply to my scenario.

Answer (score 2):

One way to do it would be to make a seperate git repository

```
mkdir combinedProject
cd combinedProject
git init
```

then add both projects as remotes to the `combinedProject`

```
git remote add -f App /path/to/App
git remote add -f Helper /path/to/Helper
```

then create separate `masterApp` and `masterHelper` branches

```
git branch masterApp --track App/master
git branch masterHelper --track Helper/master
```

then create a master branch from `masterApp` and merge `masterHelper` into it.

```
git checkout masterApp
git checkout -b master
git merge masterHelper
```

---

## Without creating a new repo you could do the same thing in the `App` repo

```
git checkout -b masterApp
```

then adding the remote for `Helper` and creating a `masterHelper` Branch

```
git remote add -f Helper /path/to/Helper
git branch masterHelper --track Helper/master
```

then mergeing `masterHelper` into `master`

```
git checkout master
git merge masterHelper
```

Comment: Thanks, I will try this out when I get back to it. Do the remote apps remain dependencies? Or can I remove them (including directories) after merging?

Comment: the remote apps aren't needed after you have added the remotes and created the `masterApp` `masterHelper` branches